# C++ enum to string conversion utility

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, enum

I needed to find a way to convert a bunch of enums to string for displaying in C++. The two main ways I found when searching was using [dark magic macros](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums) or [voodoo magic template metaprogramming](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum).

As I don't know much about any of them I thought building something myself would be a good opportunity to learn new things. Here are the features I wanted:

- enum to string only (no string to enum)
- can be added on top of legacy code (no change in enum declaration)
- mapping generated at compile time
- can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (clang/gcc) or `__FUNCSIG__` (msvc), but with a fallback displaying something somewhat useful on compilers without them
- works on enum declared inside a class
- works on enum with duplicate values (ok to return identical strings)
- use as little macro as possible, and limited to "simple" ones (e.g. defining a function is ok, defining 64 int-postfixed macros chains is not)
- can be used for small contiguous enums as well as ones with large arbitrary gaps between values
- fully automatic mapping, or at least don't crash at runtime if enum was updated with new value and the string conversion call was not
- be as simple as possible so future me will still be able to understand what's is going on

Here is the result! I'm strill trying to simplify the declaration process to remove the macro and/or allow calling it right below the enum declaration in a header file but I haven't figured it out yet.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/vWvWbnTjY)

Usage example

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum class Test : char
{
    neg = -8,
    a = 0,
    more_a = a,
    b = 3,
    c
};
// Looks like someone forgot to update after adding Test::c, no problem
DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER_RANGE(Test, Test::neg, Test::b);

enum class Test2 : unsigned short
{
    a = 1 << 0,
    b = 1 << 1,
    c = 1 << 2,
    d = 1 << 3,
    e = 1 << 4,
    f = 1 << 5,
    g = 1 << 6,
    h = 1 << 7,
    i = 1 << 8,
    j = 1 << 9,
};
DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER_LIST(Test2,
    Test2::a,
    Test2::b,
    Test2::c,
    Test2::d,
    Test2::e,
    // forgot f, everything is still fine
    Test2::g,
    Test2::h,
    Test2::i,
    Test2::j);

int main()
{
    std::cout 
        << Test::neg << '\n'     // Test::neg
        << Test::a << '\n'       // Test::a
        << Test::more_a << '\n'  // Test::a
        << Test::b << '\n'       // Test::b
        << Test::c << '\n'       // (Test)4
        << '\n'
        << Test2::a << '\n'      // Test2::a
        << Test2::b << '\n'      // Test2::b
        << Test2::c << '\n'      // Test2::c
        << Test2::d << '\n'      // Test2::d
        << Test2::e << '\n'      // Test2::e
        << Test2::f << '\n'      // (Test2)32
        << Test2::g << '\n'      // Test2::g
        << Test2::h << '\n'      // Test2::h
        << Test2::i << '\n'      // Test2::i
        << Test2::j << '\n';     // Test2::j
}
```

enum_stringifyer.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifndef ENUM_STRINGIFYER_HPP_
#define ENUM_STRINGIFYER_HPP_

#include <type_traits>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

namespace enum_stringifyer
{
    template <auto V>
    constexpr auto enum_value_name() noexcept
    {
        static_assert(std::is_enum_v<decltype(V)>, "enum_value_name requires enum value");

        // Extract value from macros, with a -1 on the size cause we don't need the last \0 in a string_view
#if defined(__clang__)// "auto enum_value_name() [V = XXXXXX::XXXXX::XXXXX]"
        constexpr std::string_view header = "auto enum_stringifyer::enum_value_name() [V = ";
        constexpr std::string_view footer = "]";
        return std::string_view{ __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ + header.size(), sizeof(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) - 1 - header.size() - footer.size() };
#elif defined(__GNUC__)// "constexpr auto enum_value_name() [with auto V = XXXXXX::XXXXX::XXXXX]"
        constexpr std::string_view header = "constexpr auto enum_stringifyer::enum_value_name() [with auto V = ";
        constexpr std::string_view footer = "]";
        return std::string_view{ __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ + header.size(), sizeof(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) - 1 - header.size() - footer.size() };
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) // "auto __cdecl enum_value_name<XXXXXX::XXXXX::XXXXX>(void) noexcept"
        constexpr std::string_view header = "auto __cdecl enum_stringifyer::enum_value_name<";
        constexpr std::string_view footer = ">(void) noexcept";
        return std::string_view{ __FUNCSIG__ + header.size(), sizeof(__FUNCSIG__) - 1 - header.size() - footer.size() };
#else
        static_assert(false, "enum_value_name requires either __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ or __FUNCSIG__ to be available");
#endif
    }

    template <class F, class T, T ... Is>
    constexpr void constexpr_for(F&& f, std::integer_sequence<T, Is...> const&)
    {
        ((f(std::integral_constant<T, Is>())), ...);
    }

    template<class Enum, Enum m, Enum M>
    struct EnumMapperRange
    {
        static_assert(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(M) >= static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(m), "M must be >= m");

        constexpr EnumMapperRange() : mapping(), start(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(m)), end(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(M))
        {
            // Same as a for loop, but with constexpr friendly i
            //for (auto i = 0; i < end - start + 1; ++i)
            //{
            //    mapping[i] = enum_value_name<static_cast<Enum>(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(m) + i)>();
            //}
            constexpr_for([this](auto i)
                {
                    mapping[i] = enum_value_name<static_cast<Enum>(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(m) + i)>();
                }, std::make_integer_sequence<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>, static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(M) - static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(m) + 1>{});
        }

        std::array<std::string_view, static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(M) - static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(m) + 1> mapping;
        const std::underlying_type_t<Enum> start;
        const std::underlying_type_t<Enum> end;
    };

    template<class Enum, Enum... pack>
    constexpr std::array<std::pair<Enum, std::string_view>, sizeof...(pack)> GetNamedEnum()
    {
        return { std::make_pair(pack, enum_value_name<pack>())... };
    }
}

#define DECLARE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER(Enum) std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Enum v)

#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#define DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER_RANGE(Enum, min_value, max_value)                                   \
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Enum v)                                           \
{                                                                                                   \
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(min_value), Enum>, "min_value must be "#Enum);            \
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(max_value), Enum>, "max_value must be "#Enum);            \
    static constexpr auto mapper = enum_stringifyer::EnumMapperRange<Enum, min_value, max_value>(); \
    if (static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(v) < mapper.start ||                              \
        static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(v) > mapper.end)                                  \
    {                                                                                               \
        return os << '(' << #Enum << ')' << static_cast<int>(v);                                    \
    }                                                                                               \
    return os << mapper.mapping[static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(v) - mapper.start];       \
} static_assert(true, "") /* To require a ; after macro call */
#else // min_value and max_value are not necessary, but keep them to get the same interface
#define DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER_RANGE(Enum, min_value, max_value)    \
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Enum v)            \
{                                                                    \
    return os << '(' << #Enum << ')' << static_cast<int>(v);         \
} static_assert(true, "") /* To require a ; after macro call */
#endif

#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#define DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER_LIST(Enum, ...)                                         \
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Enum v)                               \
{                                                                                       \
    static constexpr auto mapper = enum_stringifyer::GetNamedEnum<Enum, __VA_ARGS__>(); \
    const auto it = std::find_if(mapper.begin(), mapper.end(),                          \
        [v](const std::pair<Enum, std::string_view>& p) { return p.first == v; });      \
    if (it == mapper.end())                                                             \
    {                                                                                   \
        return os << '(' << #Enum << ')' << static_cast<int>(v);                        \
    }                                                                                   \
    return os << it->second;                                                            \
} static_assert(true, "") /* To require a ; after macro call */
#else // value list is not necessary, but keep it to get the same interface
#define DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER_LIST(Enum, ...)   \
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Enum v)            \
{                                                                    \
    return os << '(' << #Enum << ')' << static_cast<int>(v);         \
} static_assert(true, "") /* To require a ; after macro call */
#endif

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirement that this code needs to work with already declared enums which's definitions you cannot change, there really is no way other than `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or using an experimental implementation of static reflections, like `reflexpr`.

Your implementation of `enum_value_name()` makes sense, but everything past that could use a *massive* re-design. Let's focus on various minor issues first:

#### Repetition of `static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>`

C++23 has added `std::to_underlying()` to eliminate this pattern, and you can easily implement it yourself:

```cpp
template <typename E>
constexpr std::underlying_type_t<E> to_underlying(E e) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```

#### Repetition in `enum_value_name()`, misuse of `static_assert`

The way you obtain the enum name between `header` and `footer` is self-documenting, so the comments are redundant. Also, you do the same thing for every compiler, but repeat your math for finding the right substring.
Also, `static_assert(false)` will always trigger (until C++23, in some situations), so basically you're failing to compile with something other than GCC, clang, or MSVC.

Here is how you can solve these problems:

```cpp
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
inline constexpr bool has_pretty_name = true;
#else
inline constexpr bool has_pretty_name = false;
#endif

template <auto V>
constexpr auto enum_value_name() noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<decltype(V)>, "enum_value_name requires enum value");
    // V == V makes the expression dependent on V.
    // The assertion only evaluates if the function template is instantiated.
    static_assert(V == V && has_pretty_name, "enum_value_name requires either __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ or __FUNCSIG__ to be available");

#if defined(__clang__)
    constexpr std::string_view header = "auto enum_stringifyer::enum_value_name() [V = ";
    constexpr std::string_view footer = "]";
    constexpr std::string_view name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    constexpr std::string_view header = "constexpr auto enum_stringifyer::enum_value_name() [with auto V = ";
    constexpr std::string_view footer = "]";
    constexpr std::string_view name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    constexpr std::string_view header = "auto __cdecl enum_stringifyer::enum_value_name<";
    constexpr std::string_view footer = ">(void) noexcept";
    constexpr std::string_view name = __FUNCSIG__;
#endif
    // extract everything between header and footer
    return name.substr(header.size(), name.length() - header.length() - footer.length());
}
```

Notice that no matter whether we use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or `__FUNCSIG__`, we can always capture this string literal in a `std::string_view`, which simplifies this code a bit.

#### Multiple Issues with `EnumMapperRange`

1. The beginning and end of the range are template parameters `m` and `M`. No one forces you to use single-character identifiers, let alone *same-single-character* identifiers with different case. The convention in the C++ standard is for all template parameters to be PascalCase, with sane names.
2. `EnumMapperRange` has non-static data members, but all of them are compile-time properties. Making them `static inline constexpr` would make more sense.
3. Your code is needlessly generic. You have made a `constexpr_for` that works with any function and any integer sequence, but you only need it in a single place, doing exactly one thing, with an integer sequence of `std::size_t`.

Let's fix those problems:

```cpp
template<class Enum, Enum Begin, Enum End>
struct EnumMapperRange
{
    using underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<Enum>;

    static inline constexpr underlying_type begin = to_underlying(Begin);
    static inline constexpr underlying_type end = to_underlying(End);
    static_assert(end >= begin, "end must be >= m");

    using array_type = std::array<std::string_view, end - begin + 1>;

    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    static constexpr array_type make_mapping(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        array_type result{};
        ((result[Is] = enum_value_name<static_cast<Enum>(begin + Is)>()), ...);
        return result;
    }

    static inline constexpr array_type mapping = make_mapping(std::make_index_sequence<array_type{}.size()>{});
};
```

#### Insufficient macro sanitization

Part of why macros are so evil is that they can be used anywhere, even in namespaces where someone has defined their own `namespace xyz::enum_stringifyer`
or `namespace xyz::std`. All non-local symbols should be accessed using their fully qualified names:

```cpp
#define DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGIFYER_RANGE(Enum, min_value, max_value)                          \
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Enum v)                                  \
{                                                                                          \
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<decltype(min_value), Enum>, "min_value must be "#Enum); \
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<decltype(max_value), Enum>, "max_value must be "#Enum); \
    using mapper = ::enum_stringifyer::EnumMapperRange<Enum, min_value, max_value>;        \
    if (::enum_stringifyer::to_underlying(v) < mapper::begin                               \
     || ::enum_stringifyer::to_underlying(v) > mapper::end)                                \
    {                                                                                      \
        return os << '(' << #Enum << ')' << static_cast<int>(v);                           \
    }                                                                                      \
    return os << mapper::mapping[::enum_stringifyer::to_underlying(v) - mapper::begin];    \
} static_assert(true, "") /* To require a ; after macro call */
```

## Fundamental Redesign

As we go further down in the code, we end up in a macro hell where operator overloads are defined in macros.
Macros should generally be minimal crutches that help us deal with minor problems that templates cannot overcome.

The implementation of `operator<<` doesn't need to be a macro at all. We can write the following:

```cpp
template <typename Enum>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Enum v)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Enum> && enum_stringifyer::has_enum_traits<Enum>::value, std::ostream&>
{
    using namespace enum_stringifyer;
    if constexpr (has_enum_traits_list<Enum>::value) {
        static constexpr auto names = make_listed_names<Enum>();
    
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(enum_traits<Enum>::list); ++i) {
            if (v == enum_traits<Enum>::list[i]) {
                return os << names[i];
            }
        }
    }
    else if constexpr (has_enum_traits_range<Enum>::value) {
        static constexpr auto names = make_range_names<Enum>();
        constexpr auto begin = to_underlying(enum_traits<Enum>::begin);
        constexpr auto end = to_underlying(enum_traits<Enum>::end); 
        
        auto underlying = to_underlying(v);
        if (underlying >= begin && underlying <= end)
        {
            return os << names[underlying - begin];
        }
    }
    
    // zero_name should be Enum::ZERO, or (Enum)0
    static constexpr std::string_view zero_name = enum_value_name<Enum{0}>();
    static constexpr std::string_view fallback_name = enum_value_enum_name(zero_name);

    return os << '(' << fallback_name << ')' << +to_underlying(v);
}
```

We need the following to make this happen:

- create an `enum_traits` template which acts as a customization point, similar to `std::iterator_traits`
- add some *"member detector idioms"* to detect what static members the user has defined in the traits
- refactor the stringification of name lists and name ranges into function templates:

  - `make_listed_names` which converts the list of enums into a list of `std::string_view`
  - `make_range_names` which converts the range of enums into a list of `std::string_view`
- an `enum_value_enum_make` function that maps `Enum::ZERO` onto `Enum`

The customization on the user's end looks like this:

```cpp
template <>
struct enum_stringifyer::enum_traits<Test> {
    static inline constexpr Test begin = Test::neg;
    static inline constexpr Test end = Test::b;
};
```

and

```cpp
template <>
struct enum_stringifyer::enum_traits<Test2> {
    static inline constexpr std::array list = {
        Test2::a,
        Test2::b,
        Test2::c,
        Test2::d,
        Test2::e,
        Test2::g,
        Test2::h,
        Test2::i,
        Test2::j
    };
};
```

*See [live implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/br1a575Tj)*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! About your redesign, I think it comes close to what magic-enum library does (at least the user customization looks similar). However, I think that right now it fails my last requirements as I wouldn't have ever been able to produce such code ^^'. I'll need to spend a lot of time reading it to understand and learn how it works. But it's more a me problem than your code's fault!